# Cisco ASA acl deny hit rule but traffic permitted

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, acl

interface "ldap"

```
access-group ldap_access_in in interface ldap
access-group ldap_access_out out interface ldap
```

I had zero hits until I started to try ssh;

```
access-list ldap_access_out line 1 extended deny tcp host 10.99.2.70 host 10.99.11.8 eq ssh (hitcnt=5) 0xa18d6298
```

If I wait ten minutes without connecting, no hits. Checking on the remote host who is logged on I can see that the source address is what I expect it to be, and capture captures the traffic.

4 minutes after the previous tries, I will now connect three times and check the hit count:

```
[user@ldap0 ~]$ ssh 10.99.11.8
Last login: Thu Nov 20 13:48:34 2014 from 10.99.2.70
[user@root0 ~]$ logout
Connection to 10.99.11.8 closed.

[user@ldap0 ~]$ ssh 10.99.11.8
Last login: Thu Nov 20 13:53:23 2014 from 10.99.2.70
[user@root0 ~]$ ^C
[user@root0 ~]$ logout
Connection to 10.99.11.8 closed.

[user@ldap0 ~]$ ssh 10.99.11.8
Last login: Thu Nov 20 13:53:24 2014 from 10.99.2.70
[user@root0 ~]$ logout
Connection to 10.99.11.8 closed.
```

And ...

```
access-list ldap_access_out line 1 extended deny tcp host 10.99.2.70 host 10.99.11.8 eq ssh (hitcnt=8) 0xa18d6298
```

I don't have sysopt permit-vpn (this is ipsec traffic incoming on outside interface, routed to ldap interface.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out 'sysopt connection permit-vpn' is implicit, meaning you don't see it in the config (unless you actually have *no sysopt connection permit-vpn*).

Comment: FYI, it's generally considered good practice to [explicitly permit or deny](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10919996/sysopt-connection-permit-vpn) vpn traffic with your acl

Comment: I do explicitly permit my vpn traffic using both ingress and egress interface access-lists, or so I thought. It was simply a matter of negating permit-vpn and most (99%) allowed access was explicitly configured in ACLs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not readily clear what the issue is. Your ASA is still acting like permit-vpn is turned on. :(

In general, it's good to have a little more flexibility than what the permit-vpn sysopt will allow you since it's global. You can apply a vpn filter to that user's group policy

I'd try this just to ensure it does work:

```
group-policy MYVPN internal
group-policy MYVPN attributes
 vpn-filter value ldap_access_out
```